# Java: Music stops 2 times, runs tirth time

Tags: java, javafx

[I'm sorry if there are some typos in this queston (not in the program itself) i normally don't speak English]

I'm making a program with some background music, I made a second class for the music. It worked normal before I added the part where it checks if the "head-program" is still running or not (The launcher[self-made] creates an empty file, the "head-program" writes something in it to say that it's launched, i close the "head-program", "close" is written in that file, this program reads it, this program stops), when I added that part the music stopped immediately after it started, when the music is played the sacond time becuse it's a timed loop it happens again but when it starts a tirth time it works normal like there is nothing wrong. I looked at it and looked on the web for possible errors but found nothing, it's pretty weard.
Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class Music{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int x = 0;

        File f = new File("bootVeryfication.dat");
        BufferedReader br;
        String text = "";

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFXPanel();
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        while(true){
                    //Starting Music
            try{
                String bip = "texures\\music.mp3";
                Media hit = new Media(new File(bip).toURI().toString());
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
                mediaPlayer.play(); 
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            while(x != 145000){        //This is (probably) the part where the music stops
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                x = x + 1;

                try{
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                    String line;
                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                        text += line;
                    }
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(text.equals("close")){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please help me?

P.S.
I know there is an infinite loop in here.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you try to create a `MediaPlayer`, then `while(x != 145000)` you sleep, is the `MediaPlayer` object not on the same thread? I would think that this is the cause of it not playing.

Comment: I’m surprised you’re able to play the music at all, since you’re calling play() outside of the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: @user123 So if that's the problem, how can i do a delayn i the loop to make it count right?

Comment: @Beau If you need to delay I would create separate threads for either

Comment: Tank you for the help.